# How to use Alertify in .NET MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I'm developing in .NET MVC 5 and I try to use messages from controller using alertify for process confirmation, error mesagges, so on...

Comment: The vendor for Alertify has usage examples and other documentation on their website.  Did you check there?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I use this in webforms:
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script",
                    "alertify.alert('Process successufl');", true); How apply this in MVC from controller.

Comment: Have you tried simply writing JavaScript code in a `script` element on the page?  This is covered in pretty much any HTML/JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: Ok I write javascript code in view, but how to send a message from controller to View for display this message ?

Comment: Start with some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  Providing a model to the view and binding the view to that model is core functionality of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're using ASP.NET MVC doesn't change the usage of Alertify in any way.  You'd still just write JavaScript code like you would on any other HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alertify.alert('Some Message');
</script>
```

If you need to alert a message from server-side code, you'd simply refer to the model just like you would for any other model value in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alertify.alert('@Model.SomeProperty');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the logging message from the server code behind as a viewdata and call the view data after button click event/handler event in your cshtml

```
     <div>
           @if (ViewData["logmsg"] != null)
              {
              <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {                                
                    alertify.success('@ViewData["logmsg"]');
                 };  
               </script>
              }
      </div>

    Option 2) 
     <div>
          @if (Model.logmsg != null)
           {
               <script type="text/javascript">
                   window.onload = function () {                                
                    alertify.success('Model.logmsg');
                 };    
               </script> 
          }
       </div>
```